# ArrayAdapter not working properly

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Ok, so this is my scenario:

Im developing a chat, using JSON (we got no Jabber server by now). There is a service asking for new chat messages every 30seconds:

```
public class ChatService extends Service {



ArrayList<NameValuePair> params;
int subnotid;
String urlaskmessages;
String response;
ArrayList<String> mensajes;

Timer timer=new Timer();

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
    subnotid=General.subnotid;
    urlaskmessages=getString(R.string.host)+getString(R.string.appnamespace)+getString(R.string.chatpedir);
    mensajes=new ArrayList<String>();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i("CHAT", "Llamamos al servicio ChatService");
            llamarServicio();
        }
    }, 0, 30000);

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void llamarServicio(){

    Thread thread=new Thread(){

        public void run(){


            params=new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subnotid", String.valueOf(subnotid)));
            try {
                response=CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(urlaskmessages, params);
                mensajes=parseJSON(response);
                if(mensajes!=null){
                    General.mensajes.clear();

                    for (int i=0;i<mensajes.size();i++){
                        General.mensajes.add(i, mensajes.get(i));
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        private ArrayList<String> parseJSON(String resp) {

            //General.mensajes=new ArrayList<String>();
            mensajes=new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONObject total;

            try {
                total = new JSONObject(resp);
                Log.i("JSON","Respuesta recibida: "+resp);
                JSONObject paso1=new JSONObject(total.getString("chat"));
                JSONArray paso2=new JSONArray(paso1.getString("mensajes"));
                //JSONArray paso3=new JSONArray(paso2.getString("mensaje"));
                for (int i=0;i<paso2.length();i++){
                    JSONObject jobj=paso2.getJSONObject(i);
                    mensajes.add(i,jobj.getString("mensaje"));
                    Log.i("JSON","Añadido objeto: "+paso2.getString(i));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mensajes;
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i("CHAT", "ChatService destruido");
    timer.cancel();

}

}
```

As you can see, I receive the response from the server, parse the JSON, and returns an ArrayList containing all the messages, which is stored in a Singleton class where I store some values (that's why the General.mensajes).
All of this happens while another Activity is open and performing his duty (send LatLng objects). That Activity must react when the user receives a new message, and open the chat Activity:

```
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{


                if(General.mensajes.size() > numerodemensajes && General.chatabierto==false){
                    Intent chat=new Intent(c, ChatActivity.class);
                    General.AzafataChat=false;
                    startActivity(chat);
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            numerodemensajes=General.mensajes.size();

        }
    }, 0, 10000);
```

In the ChatActivity, I have a handler to react to to the arriving of a new message, and assign the Adapter::

```
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            madapter = new MessageAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, General.mensajes);
            setListAdapter(madapter);
        }

    });
```

And, finally, the adapter:

```
public class MessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private final Context context;
//private final ArrayList<Message> list;
private final ArrayList<String>list;
private Bitmap x;
String remitente;
String message;
String remite;
String mensaje;
private int numberOfItems;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MessageAdapter(Context context, int textresourceViewid,
        ArrayList<String> messages) {
    super(context, textresourceViewid, messages);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = messages;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return this.list.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return this.list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    numberOfItems=list.size();
    try {

        message = list.get(position);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();

    }
    //ViewHolder holder=new ViewHolder();
    if (v == null) {

        if (message.split(":")[0].equals("personal")){
            //holder=new ViewHolder();
            Log.i("CHAT", "En la lista hay "+list.size()+" mensajes");
            Log.i("CHAT", "El mensaje dice: "+list.get(0).split(":")[1]);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.chatsenderlayout, null);    
            if (message != null) {
                TextView texto=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textaza);
                texto.setText(message);



            }
        }else{
            Log.i("CHAT", "Estamos en el else");
        //holder=new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.chatazafatalayout, null);
        if (message != null) {
            TextView texto=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textaza);
            texto.setText(message);



        }



    }


    }       
    return v;
}



public int getLastIndex() {
    int last = 0;
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        last = list.size() - 1;
    }
    return last;
}


}
```

After all this, the problem:

When ChatActivity is open, it shows only the last 5 messages...repeated, I mean: if there are 12 messages in the ArrayList, the ChatActivity shows 12 messages, but only the 5 last messages: 8,9,10,11,12,8,9,10,11,12,8,9.

I am getting mad about this... I think it should work ok, but it doesn't. Anybody can help me?

I know it is a bit (or a lot...) messy. If you dont understand something feel free to ask.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why haven't you considered the `else` case for  `if (v == null)` in the `getView` method? What if the view is a recycled view?

Comment: Good point... I have so many things in my head i didnt realized that. Going to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your adapters getView method, you have a pass for when v == null, but not path for when v is not null, so when the listview does view recycling, and the convertView parameters passed to your getView method is not null, your method does nothing and so the previous view is shown (showing the old row data). You need to add the case where v != null, and update the existing view accordingly.

Comment: Hmm...should I simply "return v" if v is not null?

Comment: That's what you're currently doing. What you need to do is update the views within v with your new data. (or as a shortterm hack to prove this is the problem, ignore the starting value of v and always inflate a new view)

Comment: Now that I force the return of a new view always, it works perfectly now. Thank you!!